# Inserting Text at Caret Position with StyledText using SWT

Tags: java, swt, caret, styledtext

How can I insert text at the caret position of a StyledText in SWT?

An example of what I mean is as follows:

I have a StyledText with "Hello, world!", in. The caret position is in between the space and w, like so (the vertical bar/pipe, "|", is my blinking cursor):

```
Hello, |world!
```

I need some sort of way to insert text, so if I did something like myMethodThatInsertsText("beautiful "), it will change the text to (vertical bar still being cursor):

```
Hello, beautiful |world!
```

Do I have to do this manually, or is there a method that I just haven't found yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`StyledText#insert(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StyledText.html#insert%28java.lang.String%29) does exactly what you want.

If text is selected within the `StyledText`, `insert` will replace that text. However, if nothing is selected, the text will be inserted at the caret position.

Comment: Thanks. When I skimmed through the docs, the name didn't really click, so I missed it.